# How to Store html content in database

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I want to store the temperatures for a year from a weather forecast web site like [this one](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KNYC/2013/4/25/CustomHistory.html?dayend=25&monthend=4&yearend=2014&req_city=NA&req_state=NA&req_statename=NA) into a database to can use it later in an android application. I tried to use Jsoup, but i only get pieces of the table containing temperatures.
Is there any way to get that html table content to can store it?

[image: table]

Comment: I would strongly reconsider trying to store raw HTML data. What's wrong with storing the data itself and rendering it in a HTML table in the view?

Comment: @christopher i need to store the data itself. i mean the temperature for each day of the month, for each month of the year. exactly how is displayed in that table. but i haven't found a way to do that. can you give some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a whole lot better if you used the [API](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/) provided by wunderground instead of using jsoup in order to screen scrape the page.
The main reasons are that the implementation will be a lot cleaner and also your implementation will be immune to stylistic changes in wunderground web pages.
Here is [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) on how to consume a REST web service with Spring.

Once you have retrieved the data from the API you could easily store the data in a database using an ORM framework like [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) since you would have already created the objects to retrieve the data.
You can make your life even easier if you use Spring with Hibernate integration to save the data. Check out [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) guide.

The guides mentioned above use [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) to make it extremely easy to get started with the Spring framework (gone are the days where it would be almost impossible for a novice to get started with a Spring project all alone)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but i need an archive of the temperatures of the last year and the API of wunderground is not providing that. I need to store those temperatures into the database to can use them in a android app.

Comment: I think that the API does have a history feature. Check out this link http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/history#city_within_the_usa__history_for_april_5__2006

Comment: @geonard that feature returns a summary of the observed weather for the specified date. it means that i have to enter each date for one year.

Comment: @laura I see! I guess screen scraping is mandatory then. You could still however use the other relevant parts of my post to go forward with your requirements

Comment: my question is how to do screen scraping to get to use Spring with hibernate?

Comment: You need to scrape the parts of the html you want with JSoup, populate an object (entity in Hibernate terms) and the use Spring-Hibernate to save that object to the database. Check out this Jsoup tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51412/discussion-between-laura-and-geoand)

Answer (score 0):

Broadly speaking, the HTML document displayed on the website would have to be parsed programmatically, tokenized, converted to suitable data types and finally stored into the database. However it should be checked whether the data on the website could be read via a SOAP webservice or something similar, as the interface would be cleaner and the approach more robust.